# Why can I not call this function using a variable as an argument in Python?

Tags: python

Example:

```
def somerando(a,b,c,d):
    if not a+b+c+d == 9000:
        return (a+b+c+d)

somerando(1,2,3,4)
```

Returns: `10`

but

```
randonumbs = [1,2,3,4]

somerando(randonumbs)
```

Gives the following error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 somerando(randonumbs)
>
> TypeError: somerando() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'b',
>   'c', and 'd'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function expects 4 arguments. `randonumbs = [1,2,3,4]` is a list (of four items); that is one argument for your function.

you could do this:

```
randonumbs = [1,2,3,4]
somerando(*randonumbs)
```

this usage of the asterisk (`*`) is discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) or in [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

Answer (score 0):

You passed *`randonumbs`* as list, means this *whole list is considered as first argument to the function `somerando`* 
You can use **`somerando(*randonumbs)`** .

 
Here, `*` means pass as *tuple* & `**` means pass as *dictionary* (key, value pair) if you use `**` in function parameters/ arguments.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The single-asterisk form of *args can be used as a parameter to send a non-keyworded variable-length argument list to functions, like below

```
randonumbs = [1,2,3,4]
somerando(*randonumbs)
```

The double asterisk form of **kwargs is used to pass a keyworded, variable-length argument dictionary to a function.

```
randonumbs = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
somerando(**randonumbs)
```